# Importing via script tag vs importing via webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I installed the mux library using npm and import it like this

```
 <script defer src="../node_modules/mux.js/dist/mux.js"></script>
```

I know that this defines some global JS variables when this script is loaded. Are scripts that are loaded this way just a bunch of `var` definitions? Are they at all compatible with ES6 imports / webpack?

Is it possible to use webpack to bundle the script instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can use [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/):
Automatically load modules instead of having to import or require them everywhere.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       muxjs: 'mux.js/dist/mux.js', // By default, module resolution path is current folder (./**) and node_modules
    })
]
```

now simply use it in your modules(files):

```
const tools = muxjs.mp4.tools;
```

Whenever `muxjs` is encountered as free variable in a module, the `'mux.js/dist/mux.js'` is loaded automatically and the `muxjs` variable is filled with the exports of the loaded module (or property in order to support named exports).

Webpack of course has a cache so this 3rd party library will only be downloaded once (unless you are working with multiple entries that load this 3rd party library).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do ES6 import for mux.js like this:

```
import muxjs from "mux.js";
```

It will be available to use e.g.

```
const transmuxer = new muxjs.mp4.Transmuxer();
```